# How to deploy from a particular address in truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have the following code in my `token_migrations.js`:

```
const WETH = artifacts.require("WETH")
const USDC = artifacts.require("USDC")

module.exports = function (deployer, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(WETH, accounts[0], 2*10**18)
    deployer.deploy(USDC, accounts[1], 50*10**18)
}
```

It gives an error of invalid number of parameters, and expectedly so, the contract constructors take only 1 argument of initialSupply, but then what should I do if I want to deploy these contracts from different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

We have to send a tx object which contains a from parameter like so:

```
const WETH = artifacts.require("WETH")
const USDC = artifacts.require("USDC")

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(WETH, 2000000000000000000n, {from : accounts[0]})
    deployer.deploy(USDC, 50000000000000000000n, {from : accounts[1]})
}
```

Also make sure to use all 3 parameters for the deploy function `deploy(deployer, network, accounts)`
otherwise it could assume incorrect value for the 2nd parameter